# Select data that was added the last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where the time is a date type. I would like to select all the records that were added the last 7 days and then out put them in an xml file. I can select all data and output it fine without a WHERE statement.

Here is the code:

```
$query_feed = "SELECT * FROM keysound_data WHERE time >=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY AND time <= CURDATE()";
$feed = mysql_query($query_feed, $dconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_feed = mysql_fetch_assoc($feed);
$totalRows_feed = mysql_num_rows($feed);



echo'<items>';
while ($row_feed = mysql_fetch_assoc($feed)){
            echo'

        <item>
            <name>'.$row_feed['Name'].'</name>
            <email>'.$row_feed['email'].'</email>
            <date>'.$row_feed['Date'].'</date>
            <description>'.$row_feed['Make'].' '.$row_feed['Model'].' '.$row_feed['Type'].'</description>
            <logon>'.$row_feed['Logon'].'</logon>
            <category>'.$row_feed['Type'].'/'.$row_feed['Make'].'</category>
            <product_search_code>'.$row_feed['Product_search_code'].'</product_search_code>
            <order_ref>'.$row_feed['Invoice'].'</order_ref>
            <product_link>'.$row_feed['Product_link'].'</product_link>
            <customer_ref>'.$row_feed['Invoice'].'</customer_ref>
            <amount>'.$row_feed['Price'].'</amount> 
            <currency>GBP</currency>
        </item>'; 
 }
 echo '</items>';
```

Not sure what's going wrong. Any help welcome

Comment: You're just missing the closing bracket of DATE_SUB()

Comment: It's not necessary to invoke the DATE_SUB function. You could just `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a bracket in your SQL to close `DATE_SUB` function.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM keysound_data 
WHERE 
    time >=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    AND time <= CURDATE()
```

Better yet, you could use [`BETWEEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) to optmize your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM keysound_data 
WHERE 
    time BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

---

**EDIT:** As @spencer7593 noticed, `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY` should be used instead of `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` for even better optimization. The query above was updated to make use of that.

Comment: For even more optimization, remove the DATE_SUB function entirely, and just use `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Comment: That works great thanks. The problem is that when actually trying to output it in the xml no data is displayed. have you got an idea why that might be?

Comment: @Ria Have you turned on [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/2752041) to see if any errors are being thrown? Also, how many rows you get when echoing `$totalRows_feed`?

Comment: echoing out totalRows_feed gives me 1, which is correct. Just don't know whit is not showing in xml output

Comment: Removed the $row_feed = mysql_fetch_assoc($feed);
$totalRows_feed = mysql_num_rows($feed); and now it does find the first and only row, not sure why this is happening but it was. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ria That was exactly the problem: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` works as a **pointer**. Read [it's description](http://br1.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-assoc-description) for better understanding. Once you call it, the first row fetched is stored in the variable (`$row_feed`, in your case) and the internal pointer is set for the next (second) row, but it doesn't exists. When you call `$row_feed = mysql_fetch_assoc($feed)` in your `while` it tries to fetch the second row, which doesn't exists. That's why removing the first `$row_feed` worked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket.

Try this-

```
time >=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND time <= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM keysound_data 
WHERE 
    time BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND now()